# How to connect YooKassa in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Does anyone have experience of connecting YooKassa to a project on SwiftUI? I'm trying to figure out their manual on the site https://github.com/yoomoney/yookassa-payments-swift But it's written in UIKit. Here is what I wrote myself, but a lot of errors. And then I don't know what to do.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import YooKassaPayments


struct ViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewControllerUkassa {
        ViewControllerUkassa()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewControllerUkassa, context: Context) {}
}

class ViewControllerUkassa: UIViewController {
    
    weak var tokenizationModuleInput: TokenizationModuleInput?
    
    var token: Tokens?
        var paymentMethodType: PaymentMethodType?
        lazy var settings: Settings = {
            if let settings = settingsService.loadSettingsFromStorage() {
                return settings
            } else {
                let settings = Settings()
                settingsService.saveSettingsToStorage(settings: settings)

                return settings
            }
        }()

   
    let tokenizationModuleInputData = TokenizationModuleInputData (clientApplicationKey: "Key for client apps",
                                                                   shopName: "Space objects",
                                                                   purchaseDescription: """
                                                                                         An extra bright comet, rotation period: 112 years
                                                                                         """,
                                                                   amount: Amount(value: 999.99, currency: .rub),
                                                                   tokenizationSettings: makeTokenizationSettings(),
                                                                   savePaymentMethod: .on)

    
    let inputData: TokenizationFlow = .tokenization(tokenizationModuleInputData)
    
    let viewController = TokenizationAssembly.makeModule(inputData: inputData,
                                                           moduleOutput: self)

    
    let tokenizationSettings = TokenizationSettings(paymentMethodTypes: paymentMethodTypes)
    
    private func makeTokenizationSettings() -> TokenizationSettings {
        var paymentTypes: PaymentMethodTypes = []

        if settings.isBankCardEnabled {
            paymentTypes.insert(.bankCard)
        }

        return TokenizationSettings(
            paymentMethodTypes: paymentTypes
        )
    }
    
    
}

extension ViewControllerUkassa: TokenizationModuleOutput {
    
    func tokenizationModule(
            _ module: TokenizationModuleInput,
            didTokenize token: Tokens,
            paymentMethodType: PaymentMethodType
        ) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.dismiss(animated: true)
            }
            
        }

        func didFinish(
            on module: TokenizationModuleInput,
            with error: YooKassaPaymentsError?
        ) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.dismiss(animated: true)
            }
        }

        func didFinishConfirmation(
            paymentMethodType: PaymentMethodType
        ) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }

 
                self.dismiss(animated: true)
               
            }
        }
}
```

Help me, please.

Comment: What are the errors? Please [edit] your question with the additional info.